# Rewrite laravel nova middleware to response 404

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-nova

I need to return 404 instead of 403 error page when regular user try to get access for admin pages.
The Nova middleware which is responsible for this is located here `/nova/src/Http/Middleware`. 
And looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Nova\Http\Middleware;

use Laravel\Nova\Nova;

class Authorize
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        return Nova::check($request) ? $next($request) : abort(403);
    }
}
```

If I change here `abort(403)` to `abort(404)` - 
It works fine and doing exactly what I need.

How can I extend this middleware to use it in my application. What should I do to rewrite middleware properly, in my application, so that I can do updates of Nova in future and do not rewrite this changes

**What I tried:**
Extend this middleware in

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Laravel\Nova\Nova;

class NovaAuthorize extends \Laravel\Nova\Http\Middleware\Authorize
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        return Nova::check($request) ? $next($request) : abort(404);
    }
}
```

and add it to my middlewares

```
protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\NovaAuthorize::class, // nova access

    ];
```

but it had no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `/app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php`

```
protected function gate()
    {
        Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
            if( !$user->isAdmin() ){ 
                abort(404);
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
```